# creating a new column using the cosine function

Tags: pyspark

I have a table. I need to create a new column, which will be the result of taking the cosine from the original one.

| Column A |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |

I tried the following option

import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (df
.withColumn('new', np.cos(F.col('Column A))))

At the same time , I received the following error:

"loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Column which has no callable sin method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`cos`** function instead of **numpy** function.

To get use numpy function you need to convert dataframe to `pandas dataframe` using `toPandas()` function.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import cos
df.withColumn('new', cos(col("A"))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always triky to make the `Numpy` to work with `Pyspark`, so I'd recommend to use `math` instead to calculate the cosine

```py
import math
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, FloatType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(10),
     (20)],
    IntegerType())

# Define a UDF to wrap the function call and define the return type
cosUDF = udf(lambda z: math.cos(z), FloatType())

df = (df .withColumn('new', cosUDF(F.col('value'))))

df.show()
```

```
+-----+----------+                                                              
|value|       new|
+-----+----------+
|   10|-0.8390715|
|   20|0.40808207|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Though this will work, usually you would want to use built-in functions (`pyspark.sql.functions.*`) instead of writing your own UDF that does the same thing as you can trust that the built-in functions would be better implemented in most cases.